# Error y advertencia en Validator W3C WordPress y Elementor

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, elementor

He hecho la verificación en https://validator.w3.org/ y me lanza varios errores y advertencias y no se como solucionarlas para el sitio. El sitio está hecho en WordPress y Elementor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Sin ver código es casi imposible ayudarte. Por favor muestra algo de lo que hiciste para poder sugerir alguna idea. Preferiblemente código. Las imágenes a pesar de ser dicientes, no ayudan mucho en estos casos.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no genera codigo. Solo cuando entro a la pagina de w3c y escribo el dominio ya me genera eso pero como tal no puedo acceder a donde se encuentra el codigo por eso no lo he subido.

Comment: Qué información de contexto hay que pueda ayudar a interpretar la situación?

Comment: El sitio est[a hecho con WordPress y Elementor este el link del reporte [enlace] (https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Frobharrisdds.com%2F)

Comment: Yo soy ignorante en el tema. Si hiciste cambios recientes, (adición de pluggins) Te sugeriría tratar de desandar pasos hasta llegar a una situación en la que el problema no se presente. Y luego averiguar requisitos y compatibilidades. Pero fíjate, **al no saber y no tener referencias concretas** sólo puedo especular y tratar de adivinar.

Comment: elementor y sus addons generalmente usan el tag `section` para cada sección del layout por lo cual no siempre hay un título dentro ( una sección de una columna fullwidth con un slider por ejemplo ) en la mayoría de los casos podes cambiar el tag `section` por un  `div` seleccionando la sección con el navigator y en las propiedades tab layout te aparece una opción "HTML element"

Answer (score 0):

Los warnings son solo recomendaciones y no mandatorios y los puedes ignorar. Uno se queja que dentro de una sección no hay headings pero ya tienes headings repartidos la página, así que tampoco es mucho problema. El otro de es de una etiqueta "role" para el elemento "<nav>" que no es necesaria porque "<nav>" ya indica la funcionalidad, pero si está no pasa nada.

Respecto los errores, provienen de que el "for" de un label debe indicar siempre un "id" de un "<input>" al que va asociada la etiqueta. En este caso debería haber un campo <input id="form-field-field_2"... para que fuera correcta. Habría que cambiar el id del campo para que coincida o, si no hay un campo asociado, puede ponerse el elemento como un texto "<p>".

Si esto lo crea un plugin de creación de formularios, prueba las opciones que te da para ese texto o prueba a cambiar el plugin por un "contact form 7" o similar, que te dará otros controles.